# A way to place multiple data within same coordinate

Tags: python, plotly, python-xarray

I'm working with a DF of 78000~ clients each with a RFV Classification(Recency, Frequency, Value)
and i'm trying to place them in a heatmap to demonstrate how they spend based on the RFV classification. But as the RFV allows only for simple integer from 1 to 5 as classification, i found it difficult to display it without them overlaping. Im trying it in plotly with Xarray.

My DF

| COD_CLIENT | RECENCY | Medium value | R | FV | RFV | RFV_Score | RFV_Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 59 | 87 | 45.45 | 3 | 3 | 33 | 6 | Potential |
| 1846 | 75 | 6.00 | 3 | 2 | 32 | 5 | Seleepers |
| 4380 | 92 | 37.95 | 2 | 3 | 23 | 5 | Seleepers |
| **object** | **int64** | **float64** | **int32** | **int32** | **int32** | **int64** | **object** |

and my (crudely drawn) heatmap i want. For example, here is each pixel being a client and each column/row being their rfv:

[image: Each pixel being a client and each column/row being their rfv]

Does anyone knows how or if can i do this?

Comment: One thing to consider is that this will be a pretty large heatmap. 78,000 pixels with each one having hover capability is lot for plotly to render in an html file. For any solution you use, you'll probably want to export it as a static image

Comment: @DerekO unfortunatelly this is the graph my supervison asked me. As it would be just for visualization, since I already did a graph to show the most important clients.  BTW, thanks for the edit.

Comment: hey @DerekO maybe you be glad to know that i did a work arownd with other grapics and delivered what i needed. Thanks for the help

Comment: I am glad to hear you found a workaround! did you end up still using plotly? if you have the time, you can add and accept your answer to help anyone who has a similar question to you in the future

Comment: i did, and it was a workaround, not a solution. I just separated the graph into 2, one with the values from each group and one for the top 5 highest member from the groups. It did the job but wasnt exactally what my supervisor nedded